# Why does this really weird bug with theano.function updates happen in my program?

Tags: python, neural-network, mathematical-optimization, theano, gradient-descent

I found my model went wrong when I use adadelta which is implemented like this:

```
def adadelta(cost, params, learning_rate = 0.012, rho = 0.95):
            grads = T.grad(cost, params)
            accumulators = [theano.shared(np.array(np.zeros(p.get_value().shape), dtype=theano.config.floatX)) for p in params]  # @UndefinedVariable
            delta_accumulators = [theano.shared(np.array(np.zeros(p.get_value().shape), dtype=theano.config.floatX)) for p in params]  # @UndefinedVariable
            updates = []
            for p, g, a, d in zip(params, grads, accumulators, delta_accumulators):
                a_new = rho*a +(1-rho)* g ** 2
                updates.append((a, a_new))  # @UndefinedVariable
                delta =  - learning_rate*g *T.sqrt(d+0.000001)/ T.sqrt(a_new + 0.000001)
                p_new = p + delta
                updates.append((p, p_new))  # @UndefinedVariable
                updates.append((d,rho*d +(1-rho)* delta ** 2 ))
            return updates
```

after several epochs of updates, the params becomes nan. But if I use only simple gradient descent which is like this:

```
def simple_gd(cost, params, learning_rate = 0.012):
            grads = T.grad(cost, params)
            updates =  [(param, param - learning_rate * grad) for param, grad in zip(params, grads)]
            return updates
```

it didn't go wrong.

The most weird thing is if I add grads to the output of the theano.function which is like this:

```
grads = T.grad(cost, params)
outputs.extend(grads)
```

adadelta doesn't go wrong either.

And when I set the optimizer is None, the problem also does not exist

What is the problem? Is the grads in adadelta collected by garbage collector?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a bug with the 'updates' input of a theano.function.

The problem seems to appear whenever the function to compute the updated value of a theano variable x is defined independently of x. On the second iteration of a theano function, even if the same values are given to the shared variable, it can screw up. Sigh :(